# SQL Server 2012 trigger: Auditing. How to see previous value of a row without shadow table

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012, audit

I am trying to create an auditing table. I have a table called `person.address` in the `AdventureWorks` 2012 database.

I am using a trigger to capture changes to the table, the only problem is I do not know if it is possible to use a trigger to capture a row BEFORE it is edited. I am trying to save resources and overheads so trying to not use a shadow table. I know there is no "Before Insert" trigger. But is there any way to capture the information contained in a row, and when someone does an insert or update, this row can be written to my audit.table before the insert is completed?

Thank you.

Comment: In an update trigger, the new version of the row(s) affected is in the `inserted` pseudo-table, and the old version of the row(s) affected is in the `deleted` pseudo-table.

Comment: Fantastic. That helps explain it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a simplistic table with two rows:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foo(a INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT dbo.foo(a) VALUES(1),(2);
```

Then an update trigger simply to demonstrate:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trfoo ON dbo.foo FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT a FROM inserted;

  SELECT a FROM deleted;
END
GO
```

The result of an action, such as:

```
UPDATE dbo.foo SET a += 1;
```

Results in:

```
a    -- this is the *new* version of these rows
----
3
2

a    -- this is the *old* version of these rows
----
2
1
```

Also, there is an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger, which allows you to perform actions before the insert (they're not called BEFORE triggers because you still have to perform the insert yourself). [More info here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3139/improve-sql-server-efficiency-by-switching-to-instead-of-triggers/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).